# Plugin for adding content to blog post

Tags: plugins, blogs, styling

I'm implementing a blog in my website and i'm looking for a plugin that will allow the users to style their posts. Like the bar here in stack overflow that lets me add images, links and such... 
I'm not looking to integrate wordpress. I already have the blog engine implemented, and I'm just looking for this kind of plugin.

Anyone know about one?

Many thanks!

Uri

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://tinyurl.com/nd3to4c

Comment: Wow, so WYSIWYG was the word my googling was missing! This is definitely it. If you want to post this as an answer i will gladly accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor that is embedable in your backend.

> WYSIWYG is an acronym for "What You See Is What You Get". In computing, a WYSIWYG editor is a system in which content (text and graphics) displayed onscreen during editing appears in a form closely corresponding to its appearance when printed or displayed as a finished product, which might be a printed document, web page, or slide presentation.

This way you can adapt a textarea to make it something like the editor you have on SO. 
Try googling "embedable WYSIWYG editor": http://tinyurl.com/nd3to4c

You'll find tons of javascript plugins that give you these features.